# How to manually register classed based routes in express

Tags: api, express, class, ecmascript-6, routes

I am building a skeleton app using express and am trying to write my endpoints as classes for clarity and scalability:

```
module.exports = class MyRoute {
    method = 'get';
    url = '/stuff';

    constructor(someService) {
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    async handler(req, res, next) {
        // handle request and response
    }
}
```

However, if i do it this way, how can i get express to register these routes? I've seen it done before at a previous job, but i can't remember how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you exactly want, I can think of many ways to take advantages of such design.

But I think this is what you want, since you have `method` and `url` attribute on your class.

`routeModule.js` file:

```js
module.exports = class MyRoute {
    method = 'get';
    url = '/stuff';

    constructor(someService) {
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    async handler(req, res, next) {
        // handle request and response
    }
}
```

`index.js` file or wherever you register your routes:

```js
const routeModule = new (require("./path/to/routeModule"))();

app[routeModule.method](routeModule.url, routeModule.handler);
```

That code will register your route dynamically by `method` name and `url`, the result will be equivalent to

```js
app.get("/stuff", routeModule.handler);
```

---

I thought of something that probably can make your code cleaner if you will register a lot of route manually. I made a function on express client to register a route module:

```js
const app = express();

app.addRouteModule = function(s) {
    this[s.method](s.url, s.handler);
}
```

Then you can call it easily to register a class as a new route:

```js
const routeModuleA = new (require("./path/to/routeModuleA"))();
const routeModuleB = new (require("./path/to/routeModuleB"))();
const routeModuleC = new (require("./path/to/routeModuleC"))();

app.addRouteModule(routeModuleA);
app.addRouteModule(routeModuleB);
app.addRouteModule(routeModuleC);

// or
app.addRouteModule(new (require("./path/to/routeModuleA"))());
app.addRouteModule(new (require("./path/to/routeModuleB"))());
app.addRouteModule(new (require("./path/to/routeModuleC"))());
```

Comment: I was experimenting with your design and I thought of something that probably can make your code cleaner, check my edit :)